# Rendering html (a hbs template) on callback from the third party API

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Here is the logic that I',m struggling with:

1. User clicks a button which triggers a `POST` request to the app API.
2. The method called makes a call to a third party API, this API returns a response immediately and then after a while also sends a callback to `returnUrl` specified in the first request.
3. The callback event arrives at the return url and is processed further in the app.

At the step 3 after the processing is over, the user should be shown a different page, that's to say, after licking the button the user should only see a spinner until the callback event arrives at the notification controller. Once the event is there and is processed, the user should see a different page.

I cannot see how to render this new page.
The way I'd like to organise implies that there should be no rendering on the notification controller. I'd like to have a special method on another controller (or a dedicated event handler should be used as an alternative) that would be called and the html then presented to the end user.
However, it's probably okay to render this second page at the first step, in the first method, but this method should not finish until the event arrives. But I'm not sure I know how to achieve that. Event though I don't like this approach either.

In angular it could be done via `router.navigate`. The question is how to implement this in NestJS? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

To implement the redirect to the new page, you have a few options:

- You can use NestJS's built-in RedirectResponse to perform the redirection within the controller method handling the initial POST request.
- Alternatively, you can use NestJS's routing system to navigate to a different endpoint that renders the new page.

Here's an example of how you might implement the redirection within the controller method:

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Redirect } from '@nestjs/common';
@Controller('api')
export class ApiController {
 @Post('trigger-action')
 async triggerAction(): Promise<any> {
 // Call third-party API
 // Process response
 // Trigger event
 // Await event completion

 return { message: 'Action triggered, please wait for callback' };
}

 @Get('callback')
 @Redirect('/new-page') // Redirect to '/new-page' endpoint
 handleCallback(): void {
 // Handle callback event
   }
}
```

In this example, the triggerAction() method is responsible for initiating the action and waiting for the callback event. Once the callback event is received and processed in the handleCallback() method, the user is automatically redirected to the '/new-page' endpoint.

This approach allows you to achieve the desired behavior without rendering the new page in the notification controller or blocking the initial method until the event arrives.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. It looks good, at least at first sight, but could you please elaborate on the second option as well. I'm very curious.

Comment: Before reading your comment, I've made up one utilising a replay subject and `firstValueFrom`, we sort of subscribe to this stream and then when a notification arrives to the notification controller we emit an event which is then received by the subscriber and the flow is continued. But it seems a little cumbersome...

Comment: I gave this a test and it does not seem to work like this. Redirection does not happen on the callback event...